# How can I print just one name for Title?

Tags: python, mysql, video, min, pgadmin

I am using Pgadmin (mysql).
I have to print one name for date (the first year)
So my code give me this:

```
"El padrino";1972
"El padrino";1972
"El padrino";1972
"El resplandor";1980
"El resplandor";1981
"Buenos muchachos";1990
"Buenos muchachos";1990
"Forrest Gump";1994
"Forrest Gump";1994
"Tiempos violentos";1994
"Tiempos violentos";1995
"Los 7 pecados capitales";1995
```

And I need to take the first name of each movie with the oldest year. Like this:

```
"El padrino";1972
"El resplandor";1980
"Buenos muchachos";1990
"Forrest Gump";1994
"Tiempos violentos";1994
"Los 7 pecados capitales";1995
```

I am trying with the following code:

```
SELECT min(titulo), MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR from f.fecha))
FROM pelicula p, f_estreno_pais f 
WHERE p.id_pelicula = f.id_pelicula
GROUP BY p.id_pelicula, f.fecha
ORDER BY f.fecha;
```

Comment: If you are looking for oldest year, shouldn't it be `MAX(...)` instead of `MIN(...)`?

Comment: Not exactly, because the oldest date is MIN(...) ! But actually my problem is with the movies name, I have to figure that out first and later I will check what you said.

Comment: I think the main problem in is in the `GROUP BY` statement. You are grouping by movie and date as a combo (star wars, 1977) is one grouping and (star wars, 1980) is  another grouping.
You should just group by movie, and then take the `MIN(YEAR)` of that grouping:
`SELECT titulo, MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR from f.fecha)) `
`FROM ...`
`WHERE ...`
`GROUP BY p.id_pelicula`
`ORDER BY f.fecha;`

Comment: I just tried what you said... But I think I did not get it. Because if i delete the date in the group by, I get the following error :"column "f.fecha" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: `MIN` is an aggregate function, it probably is the order of operation. If you try `MIN(f.fecha)` does it work? If it does, you can then try `EXTRACT(YEAR from MIN(f.fecha))`
If you removed the `MIN` from titulo and it fails, you should put it back `-> SELECT MIN(titulo), MIN(f.fecha)` only grouping by `id_pelicula`

Comment: That worked, yes! EXTRACT(YEAR from MIN(f.fecha)). Now I just need to print just one movie for date! :(

Comment: I have almost the same code that I posted... Only changed the EXTRACT(YEAR from MIN(f.fecha)). But also, it can not be grouped only id_pelicula, because I have the ERROR I wrote 2 messages ago (column f.fecha.....)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention you database system. If there are windwos functions this would be one way:

Prepare a common table expression (cte). Your table has column "titulo" and "fecha". Number them by "fecha" per "titulo" and take the first number from your cte.

For SQL-Server the syntax would be like

```
;with my_cte as (
   select
      titulo,
      fecha,
      row_number() over (partition by titulo order by fecha) n
   from your_table
 )
select *
from my_cte
where n = 1
```

other database systems are similar. "Mixing" tables is called "to join two tables". Your syntax is very old-school. You'd better use modern join syntax if your database system supports this.

For SQL-Server 2016 this would be a complete running example what would give your expected results:

```
drop table if exists #t1
create table #t1 (titulo varchar(255), fecha int)

insert  #t1 values
 ('El padrino',1972),
 ('El padrino',1972),
 ('El resplandor',1980),
 ('El resplandor',1981),
 ('Buenos muchachos',1990),
 ('Buenos muchachos',1990),
 ('Forrest Gump',1994),
 ('Forrest Gump',1994),
 ('Tiempos violentos',1994),
 ('Tiempos violentos',1995),
 ('Los 7 pecados capitales',1995)


 ;with my_cte as (
   select
      titulo,
      fecha,
      row_number() over (partition by titulo order by fecha) n
   from #t1
 )
select *
from my_cte
where n = 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Ooh I forgot. I am using pgadmin 3 (sql)... I think it can support a modern join syntax. I am new at this... Just a few months so I do not have too mucho knowledge :)

Comment: Your code it make sense. But it prints the same date for all the movies (like if every movie has the same date)

Comment: If you order you window function on date and take the first - it will be the first. Just play around with it.

Comment: "El guason";1972    
"Vivarium";1972
"Criatura de la noche";1972
"Gladiador";1972
"En busca de la felicidad";1972
"Buenos muchachos";1972           So... I am getting this with your code... Maybe I put something wrong, but what I need is to get the first date for each movie. Not the first for all... I do not know if I am describing correctly my problem

Comment: Maybe it is a goot idea to build a running example. There should be your input data, your script and the expected results. If you are using mysql you could mention this. As there is sql as well this is not a 100% must-be - your expected results are! Your script should run when copied into a IDE 'as-is".

Comment: "partition by" makes a window over the group of members.When you paratition by movie and order them by datem there sould be a number for each movie. You can try the cte as single statement. It is like a temporary table.

Comment: Now I edited the post. It is easier now to understand what I need.

Comment: see my edited answer with a soution that gives exactly your results

Comment: Thanks! But I do not have to delete the tables if it exist. With your code I get this: "Buenos muchachos";"1972-10-05";2
"Criatura de la noche";"1972-10-05";2
"El club de la pelea";"1972-10-05";2
"El guason";"1972-10-05";2
"El hoyo";"1972-10-05";2
"El origen";"1972-10-05";2
"El padrino";"1972-10-05";2

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like exactly a PostgreSQL `SELECT DISTINCT ON` query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (titolo)
    titolo, ano
    ORDER BY titolo, ano;
```

The downside of this is that it's PostgreSQL-specific extension, it's not portable to other databases; depending on your situation, this may or may not be important.

Comment: In this case the DISTINCT does not make any difference :/, need a difference query

Comment: This is DISTINCT ON; that gives the first row in each group, then the ORDER BY is used to make sure the first row is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT min(p.titulo), MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR from f.fecha)) min_fecha
 FROM pelicula p
 INNER JOIN f_estreno_pais f ON p.id_pelicula = f.id_pelicula
 GROUP BY p.id_pelicula
 ORDER BY min_fecha;
```

That was the solution!